# Remotely Starting Program with fork() on VM

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, sh, fork

I have a setup with a host having multiple VMs. Now I have written a C program which is to be run on each of the VMs individually andI want this program to be started remotely from the host.

The problem is that the start of this program causes a new forked child process to be created (program has code with fork()). So when I use the following script to start this program:

**Run.sh (this is run at the host):**

ssh VM1 'program start'
ssh VM2 'program start'
ssh VM3 'program start'

The script stops after execution of line 1 (ssh VM1 "program start"). I think this happens because a fork child process gets started and is running and unless it exits, the calling sh script cannot proceed.

As a result the program only gets started on VM1 and my Run.sh script gets stuck.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Running in background

```
ssh VM1 'program start' &
ssh VM2 'program start' &
ssh VM3 'program start' &
```

Try it `&` inside `'`

```
ssh VM1 'program start &'
```